# Bootstrap - Giving Small Spacing Between Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, spacing

I am trying to adapt a layout on Bootstrap that I got from the designer. Two columns in the content has a small spacing, that I couldn't achieve with direct column-spacing (as it gives too much gap). Thus, I tried wrapping everything into a row and adding sub-columns inside my main columns. Here in the code, it's more clear:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 banner"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-12 leftSide">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 leftSide">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 rightSide">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Now the spacing seems good but as I wrapped it in a row (I think), the right panel overflowed more then the banner.

It can be seen more clear on the fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/gMBrLvaK5C

The problem is the 'rightSide' panel.

How can I keep that spacing between 'leftSide' and 'rightSide', and fix the overflowing of the right column (because the spacing gets too much if I try achieving spacing with columns)? Or what is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is my personal solution, instead of add a class on the columns, create a div inside of a column, then you can place a `div.banner` and `div.block` like my example:

http://www.bootply.com/PEIiDnp9VD

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="banner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want less space between the columns you can simply override Bootstrap `col-md-*` class by adding a class on the columns changing the padding left and right.

Comment: Left-side is off now. :S I don't want to change the size of banner (which will cause left-side's size to get bigger too). This is not what I want. What I want to achieve is making right panel's right-side smaller.

Comment: yeah... if remove padding-left from leftSide that works... i will try again

Comment: You can also add a `margin-left: -15px;` to the `.leftSide` class. See [here](http://www.bootply.com/eIkTDhTvyQ)

Comment: @zgood yes, but widening the space is what I don't want to achieve. I want to keep the spacing of left-panel and right-panel as it is, not widening them. This was my problem in the first place. Also I tried adding `margin-left: -15px` to rightSide, but doesn't work. Here is a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/Ru1qRyDLUj)

Comment: @Leandro As far as I understand, it is not rational to change the default sizing. Thanks for your time though :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to follow proper wrapping of rows and columns. If you want consistency you need to make sure all columns are wrapped into a row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 leftSide">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 rightSide">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply custom margins and styling to elements inside of the columns, not columns themselves.

http://www.bootply.com/g6eLHRd1tH